# How to use the FragmentPagerAdapter with unique unrelated fragments?

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I am trying to implement a simple swiping action between the three main screens of my app (feed, forum & profile).
I've been looking for guides online but they all seem to take the same approach and show how to implement the adapter using fragments that are simple instances of a basic class that for example just inflates a title and a number on the screen.

In my case, the fragments are not all instances of the same class and are completely different.

M problem lays in the FragmentPagerAdapter. I am not sure how to return each fragment in the getItem method.

I have tried the following but it doesn't except it as a valid return statement and is still expecting one:

```
class PagesPagerAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {


    override fun getItem(p0: Int): Fragment? {

        return when (p0){

            0 -> FeedFragment.newInstance()
            1 -> BoardFragment.newInstance()
            2 -> ProfileFragment.newInstance()
            else -> FeedFragment.newInstance()
        }

    }



    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return 3
    }
}
```

This is an example of one of my fragments:

```
class FeedFragment : Fragment() {

    val galleryAdapter = GroupAdapter<ViewHolder>()


    private fun setUpGalleryAdapter() {

        feed_gallary.adapter = galleryAdapter
        val galleryLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this.context, 3)
        feed_gallary.layoutManager = galleryLayoutManager

        val dummyUri =
            "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/dere-3d530.appspot.com/o/20150923_100950.jpg?alt=media&token=97f4b02c-75d9-4d5d-bc86-a3ffaa3a0011"

        val imageUri = Uri.parse(dummyUri)
        if (imageUri != null) {
            galleryAdapter.add(FeedImage(imageUri))
            galleryAdapter.add(FeedImage(imageUri))
            galleryAdapter.add(FeedImage(imageUri))
            galleryAdapter.add(FeedImage(imageUri))
            galleryAdapter.add(FeedImage(imageUri))


        }
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        setUpGalleryAdapter()

    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? =
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false)


    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): FeedFragment = FeedFragment()
    }

}
```

And this is my main activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    private lateinit var viewPager: ViewPager
    private lateinit var pagerAdapter: PagesPagerAdapter


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        viewPager = findViewById<ViewPager>(R.id.view_pager)

        pagerAdapter = PagesPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
        viewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter

    }
}
```

I have also tried to define a variable currentFragment, have it reassigned for each of the when statements and have it be the return value, but as all my fragments are unique I am getting a type mismatch when trying to assign them all to one variable.

Is there some Array I can store the fragments in and then return the array position?

I feel like there is probably a simple elegant and common solution here.

Comment: What you have should work just fine. Are your `Fragments` the same type as the expected return statement of the `FragmentPagerAdapter`? Specifically are you using the support version of the pager adapter and the non support version of the fragment? or vice versa? Also, make sure you are returning an instance of the fragment and not the class representation of your fragments.

Comment: @Bobbake4 thanks for the reply.

I have indeed passed the class representation of the fragment. I feel like I should know the answer to that, but how would I pass an instance of it? Just create something like `var mFeedFragment = FeedFragment()` and pass that?
Also I am not sure what you mean by the support version/no-support version.

Comment: Your `getItem()` function doesn't have a return value, you need to place a `return` in front of `when`. And if you are using a `when` statement you'll need a valid `else` block. Either way I think @Valerii's answer is a better solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing all of your code I cannot be sure but one thing to note is you must return an instance of your fragment not a reference to the class. Ex: `FeedFragment()` instead of `FeedFragment`.

Also, your `when` statement does not have a default case resulting in a compile error for the `getItem` method as you have a code path that doesn't return anything. Try the following code for `getItem`

```
override fun getItem(p0: Int): Fragment {

    when(p0){
        0 -> return FeedFragment.newInstance()
        1 -> return BoardFragment.newInstance()
        else -> return ProfileFragment.newInstance()
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, @Bryan makes a good point about leveraging the `return` before the `when` statement.

Comment: Appreciate your answers Bob. I still can't make it work not sure why. I've updated my answer with the current adapter based on your answer (a little different though as I've placed the return before the when statement. Was that your meaning?). I've also attached my mainActivity code. Really nothing else to my code other than the two other fragment that just have some basic objects in them for the moment to see if the pager works.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no elegant solution for this case. You can store created fragment in array and then use this array when you need to access related fragment instance.

```
class PagesPagerAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {
    private val fragments = SparseArray<WeakReference<Fragment>>()

    override fun getCount() = 3

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment? {
        val fragmentReference = fragments[position]
        return if (fragmentReference?.get() != null) {
            fragmentReference.get()
        } else {
            return when (position) {
                0 -> FeedFragment.newInstance()
                1 -> BoardFragment.newInstance()
                2 -> ProfileFragment.newInstance()
                else -> error("Incorrect position: $position")
            }
        }
    }

    override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {
        val fragment = super.instantiateItem(container, position) as Fragment
        fragments.put(position, WeakReference(fragment))
        return fragment
    }
```

Comment: I believe you need to return `fragments[position].get()` to return the `Fragment` (instead of the `WeakReference` object).

Comment: Appreciate your answer Valerii! I am not familiar with these function so trying ro figure this out. I am receiving an unresolved reference notice for the `it` in `fragments.put(position, WeakReference(it))` . Also (and maybe that's also the answer for my first question), how do I add my fragments to this array?
I've tried this `fragments.put(position, WeakReference(FeedFragment))` but I'm sure you know that's not working

Comment: There should be `fragment` instead of `it`. I edited the answer. Fragment will be added to array in `instantiateItem` method (adapter will handle it inside by itself). 
`getItem` method will decide which type of fragment should be created depending on position.
You also will need to override `getCount` method so that adapter will know how many fragments it should create.